# MDADM RAID 5 disk missing after reboot

Tags: linux, debian, raid, software-raid

I have a server with 6 disks (4x2TB + 2x4TB). I put the 2TB disks in 2 RAID 0 and the resulting 2 4TB RAIDs with the 2 4TB disks in a RAID 5 array. The RAID works fine until I reboot the server. After the reboot the server starts the RAID in a degraded state (U_UU) (disk 2, which is a RAID 0, missing). I can re-add the missing drive which triggers a resync that takes about 20 hours. after that the raid works fine again until I reboot again. Upon another reboot the scenario repeats itself. Disk 2 missing, RAID degraded... 
How can I make my RAID start correctly?

I am using debian wheezy 7.4

let me clarify the setup

I have the following disks:
sda: 2TB
sdb: 2TB
sdc: 2TB
sdd: 2TB
sde: 4TB
sdf: 4TB

and the following RAIDs:
sda + sdb RAID0 -> md0: 4TB
sdc + sdd RAID0 -> md1: 4TB
md0 + md1 + sde + sdf RAID5 -> md2 12TB

Comment: I'm confused. So you have RAID 0 on 4x2TB and no raid on the 2x4tb drives, you then RAID 5 the RAID0 + 2x4TB drives and this is what fails after reboot? If so, I'm not suprised. Logical drives are not supposed to be part of software RAID arrays. In fact, I'm surprised the system even let you select it to add to the RAID 5 in the first place! Why on earth do you need a striped 8TB set of discs when the system will only ever use 4TB of it in the RAID 5 anyway?

Comment: Hi Simkill, thanks for your interrest. I added a clearer description of my setup in the question. I hope it helps you understand my situation.

Comment: You could try hardware RAID 0 on those 2TB discs and software RAID 5within debian. At least you can guarantee the drive will always be presented to the operating system as single disc rather. Most people steer clear of software raid completely because it's considered less reliable than hardware raid.